# Place images in with row count

Tags: visualforce

How can I display the images horizontally? Tried placing values for columns but didn't work. I'm basically looking to display images in Facebook style like 4 images in 1st row, 4 images in 2nd row etc . Please help!

```
<apex:page controller="test_allbuckets_controller" tabStyle="Document" action="{!constructor}">
 <apex:outputPanel id="fullRefreshPageId">
  <apex:form >

  <br/>
<apex:pageBlock title="Force.com for Amazon Web Services">
<apex:pageMessages />


<!--  THIS PAGE BLOCK SECTION ILLUSTRATES HOW TO LIST ALL OBJECTS IN A SPECIFIC BUCKET -->
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="List all Objects in selected Bucket">

<apex:actionFunction status="statusForListBucket" action="{!listBucket}" name="listBucket" rerender="listBucketResults">
            <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!bucketToList}" value="" />
            <apex:param name="secondParam" assignTo="{!renderListBucketResults}" value="true" />
</apex:actionFunction>

 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText value="Select the Bucket to list all Objects for:" />
   <apex:selectList onclick="listBucket(this.value)" value="{!bucketToList}" multiselect="false" >
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!BucketNames}"/>
    </apex:selectList><br/>
   </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

   <apex:outputPanel id="listBucketResults">
    <apex:actionstatus id="statusForListBucket">
                    <apex:facet name="start">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; color: red; background-color:white;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacting S3 to generate list of Objects..results below will be populated upon response....&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </span>
                    </apex:facet>

                    <apex:facet name="stop">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!ISNULL(listBucketErrorMsg))}">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; color: red; background-color:white;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ERROR: {!listBucketErrorMsg}
                        </span>

                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>

 </apex:actionstatus>
    <br/>

  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(bucketToList) ,false,true)}" id="popImage">
  <br/>

    <apex:dataTable cellpadding="2" value="{!bucketList}" var="obj" >
        <apex:facet name="caption">
           <apex:outputText value="List of Objects stored in the Bucket: {!bucketToList}" style="font-weight:bold; color:red;" />
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:column width="75">
        <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
       </apex:column>

  <apex:column width="300" >
             <apex:commandLink value="{!obj.Key}" action="{!redirectToS3Key}" target="_blank">
                 <apex:param name="filename" value="{!obj.Key}"/>
             </apex:commandLink>  

 <style>        
img {
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease;
    }

img:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
} 
</style>
          <apex:image id="theImage" value="     https://s3.amazonaws.com/{!bucketToList}/{!obj.key}?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGN4J4RSRNW26IEA&amp"  width="150" height="150">
 </apex:image>  
     </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable> 
  </apex:outputPanel> 
       <apex:actionstatus id="statusForDeleteKey">
                    <apex:facet name="start">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; color: red; background-color:white;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacting S3 to generate delete Object......&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </span>
                    </apex:facet>

                    <apex:facet name="stop">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(AND(!ISNULL(deleteObjectErrorMsg),deleteObjectErrorMsg!='Success'))}">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; color: red; background-color:white;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ERROR: {!deleteObjectErrorMsg}
                        </span>
                       </apex:outputPanel>
                   </apex:facet>
               </apex:actionstatus> 
   </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
   </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination of [apex:panelGrid](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm) and CSS:

```
<apex:page>

<style type="text/css">
td.quarter: {
    width: 25%;
}
img.fill {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<apex:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="quarter, quarter, quarter, quarter">
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
    <apex:image styleClass="fill" value="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/magdalena-carmen-frieda-kahlo-y-calderón-de-rivera/self-portrait-time-flies-1929.jpg"/>
 </apex:panelGrid>

</apex:page>
```

produces this four image across layout:

[image: sample output]